# Auto-incrementación desde anterior ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

¡Hola! Hace un tiempo tengo un problema con la **auto-incrementación** en una de mis tablas en **MySQL**. Al principio no tenía problemas ya que no tenía necesidad de eliminar ningún dato dentro de la tabla, pero cuando comencé a eliminar algunos registros, los ID **no se iban auto-incrementando** teniendo en cuenta el valor del **ID anterior**.

Con esto me refiero a que, por ejemplo, si ingreso valores con el ID 3 y luego lo borro, cuando quiera ingresar otros valores, **se me asignará el ID 4** en vez de tomar el ID 2 (teniendo en cuenta que el ID 3 fue eliminado anteriormente). Me imagino que los valores de ID quedan almacenados en algún lado causando este inconveniente.

[image: Tabla de datos de referencia]

Como se muestra en la imagen, al principio no tuve problemas pero luego del ID 7 los valores fueron incrementando tomando de referencia **otros valores que se habían eliminado anteriormente**.

¿Es posible que de alguna manera al actualizar, eliminar o enviar alguna consulta hacia la base de datos ésta **también me actualice los ID**? Teniendo en cuenta que el orden debería ser 1, 2, 3, etc.

¡Muchas gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El ID es identificador único para cada uno de tus registros. No tiene sentido que al eliminar se reinicien, si lo que deseas en contar los registros existen otros métodos sin necesidad de tocar el ID. De igual manera con auto_increment no vas a poder hacer lo qeu refieres.

No se especificamente por qué desearías reiniciar los ID al eliminar, pero igual la solución a tu problema puede estar en usar UUID...
Indaga al respecto y luego valora...

Comment: ¡Hola! Entiendo qué es el ID y no me refiero a que se "reinicien", si no que el valor del entero sea siguiendo un orden teniendo en cuenta el anterior (como lo aclaré anteriormente, sería 1, 2, 3, etc). No necesito utilizar un UUID ya que el programa no lo requiere en este caso, de todas formas te comento que indagué este problema con anterioridad y no encontré una solución clara a lo que estoy buscando. ¡Saludos!

Comment: El ID cuando está configurado en auto_increment se va general automaticamente dependiendo del último ID registrado. Ejemplo, introduces 1, 2, 3, eliminas el 2 y simpre va adetectar que el ultimo ID es el 3, incluso si eliminas el 3 va a continuar en el 4... No existe vía de cambiar eso... Expón bien lo que deseas implementar para que sea necesario organizar los ID de la manera en que quieres, quizas la solución esté en otro metodo...

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información respecto al auto_increment. Pensaba que, de alguna manera, se hubiera podido modificar para así obtener el resultado que buscaba. Deseo implementar la regla de "1, 2, 3, etc" para mantener un orden en la tabla y no tener los ID "desordenados" ya que estan tomando un número que no corresponden (no sé si se entiende bien, pero me refiero a que si elimino un registro con el ID incluido, necesitaría que ese espacio quede "desocupado" para el siguiente ingreso de datos). Saludos.